# Changing Option Menu after pressing Back button when using Fragments and back stack?

Tags: java, android, fragment

I am using one single activity where I replace a fragment with another when the user select an menu item from the options menu.

I have implemented the back stack using `addToBackStack()` and `onBackPressed()`.

Everything works fine, except that when a user pressed the Back button, the fragment is replaced but the Options menu is showing the previous item.

How can I make it so that the Options Menu changes back to the previous item when the user pressed the Back button?

Comment: Did you looked at the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29 method of the `Activity`?